# Unit Testing - database and fixtures

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

I am just starting to get into unit testing and cant see an easy way to do a lot of test cases due to the interaction with a database.

Is there a standard method/process for unit testing where database access (read and write) is required in order to assert tests?

The best I can come up with so far is to have a config file used to bootstrap my app using a different db connection and then use the startup method to copy over the live db to a db used in isolation for tests?

Am I close?  Or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: In this blog post I've shown an example of test/production databases and fixtures to fill test database using Go language: https://automationangels.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/fixtures-propagating-test-database-for-unit-tests-in-go/  Take a look, it might be useful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your business logic shouldn't directly interact with the Database. Instead it should go through a data access layer that you can fake and mock in the context of unit testing. Look into mocking frameworks to do the mocking for you. Your tests should not depend on a database at all. Instead you should specify the data returned from your data access layer explicitly, and then ensure that your business logic behaves correctly with that information.

Testing that the program works with a DB attached is more of an integration test, and those have a lot of costs associated with them. They are slower (so it's harder to run them every time you compile), and more complicated (so they require more time and effort to maintain). If you can get simpler unit tests in place, I would recommend you do that first. Later you can add integration tests that might use the DB as well, but you'll get the most value from adding simpler unit tests first.

Comment: Hi Oleski, thanks.  That makes sense, though in my situation the app is tightly coupled to the database. It is a custom ecommerce shopping cart.  There are a lot of situations that require database access, for example adding an item to the shopping requires that this is stored in the database etc. So im not sure how to mock that

Comment: @user1189880 One of the large benefits of having tests in my mind, is that it forces you to refactor your code to make it more testable. If you can refactor your code, you will be much better off in the longer run. If you can't refactor for whatever reason, I would create a different database instance that gets cleared and populated with data before each test gets run.

Answer (score 4):

As far as unit-test go, I think whatever works for you in practice is the way to go. It's important that unit tests give you some value and improve the quality of your system and your ability to develop and maintain it.

I would suggest you probably don't want to be copying the live db over to your test db. There's probably no guarantees that your live database will contain suitable data that will cause your unit-tests to consistently run. The unit-tests should test that your code works, they shouldn't be testing that the live database happens to contain suitable data that causes them to pass, because as it's live, your users might change the content of it so that your tests fail.

You're unit test code itself should probably populate your test db with data required that simulates the scenarios you want to write unit tests for. I messed around with some ruby on rails code a few years ago; the test framework for that would have a test class which setup the db with some fake data, then multiple test methods from the class would be written to run against that data, and the tear-down method would wipe data from the database. So, different test-classes (or sometimes people call them fixtures) would run against a certain data setup, that meant you could run a number of tests against the same data setup instead of creating it for every test case you wanted to run. Setting up data for every test could end up causing your tests to run slowly, such that you get bored of waiting for them to run and stop bothering with them.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this wouldn't be a unit test anymore. It'd be an integration test, and integration tests have a lot of cost associated with them. For example, they're much slower and much more complicated. The OP should probably try to implement unit tests first.

Comment: That all depends on where you draw the boundaries between your units. You have to chop isolated pieces of functionality out of your program to test them. That could be expressions, statements, functions, sets of functions, classes, etc. Basically... whatever you feel gives you the most bang for your buck.

Comment: I agree the convention seems to be that a unit-test should test stuff within one process; testing at a class level seems to be the convention for object-oriented languages. Unit-testing as it's defined academically does seem like a good thing to aim for, but if writing and maintaining the unit tests ends up taking too much time compared to the benefits they give, then a better balance needs to be made. And I'm prepared to relax the definition of unit-test. :)